# How did you create the animations on the 'our team' page?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange-team

These are awesome: https://stackexchange.com/about/team

My favourite is Steve Feldman's.

Answer (score 7):

Those are just animated gifs that get loaded when you hover over the static image and replace it.

Animated gifs are easy to make with any modern image editor - they are just a bunch of frames and timing.

Comment: @Downvoter - care to comment?

Comment: I guess you've taken the "magic" away from someone. Until they read your answer it was all unicorns and glitter. I can't say I'm not upset myself, but I'll let it slide this time. ;)

Comment: Think the OP meant how you took the pictures e.g. what kind of camera, where, etc.